# Question in proof of Theorem 6.9 (Part |||) Hungerford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am self studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I have a question in proof of Theorem 6.9 on page 223 of Unit ||| .

It's image: [image]

> Question is in line 6 of proof : what is the reasoning behind deducing that $π(a_{1} ) = 0 $ ?

I am confused as author didn't gave any explanation for that  .

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a decomposition $A=Ra_1 \oplus C$, and $\pi$ is the canonical projection given by $\pi(ra_1 + c) = c$. Thus, $\pi(a_1)=\pi(a_1+0)=0$.